# Neo4j Cypher Query 1.9.6 issue using Java API

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I am using  the following query

```
     START n=node(*)
     MATCH(n)
     WHERE n.Gender ?="Female"
     RETURN n
```

which runs perfectly in the server.

My program is as follows

```
    void query()
      {
      ExecutionResult result,;
       Transaction tx=null;
     ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine( graphDb );

    try
    {
        String name="Female";
        tx=graphDb.beginTx();
     result=engine.execute("start n=node(*)match(n)where n.Gender ?={Female} return n");
       System.out.println(result.dumpToString());
       tx.success();
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        try
        {           
            File f=new File("trace.txt");
            BufferedWriter br=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f,true));
            tx.failure();
            k=Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace());
            System.out.println(k);
            br.write(k);
            br.close();
            throw new IOException();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
      }
    finally
    {
        tx.finish();
    }

}
```

when I try to execute it through the program it enters the catch block and prints the following stacktrace

```
            [org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.QueryState$$anonfun$getParam$1.apply(QueryState.scala:60),
             org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.QueryState$$anonfun$getParam$1.apply(QueryState.scala:60),
             scala.collection.MapLike$class.getOrElse(MapLike.scala:128), 
             scala.collection.AbstractMap.getOrElse(Map.scala:58), 
             org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.QueryState.getParam(QueryState.scala:60), 
             org.neo4j.cypher.internal.commands.expressions.ParameterExpression.apply(ParameterExpression.scala:27), 
             org.neo4j.cypher.internal.commands.Equals.isMatch(ComparablePredicate.scala:59),
             org.neo4j.cypher.internal.commands.NullablePredicate.isMatch(Predicate.scala:59),
             org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.FilterPipe$$anonfun$internalCreateResults$1.apply(FilterPipe.scala:30), 
             org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.FilterPipe$$anonfun$internalCreateResults$1.apply(FilterPipe.scala:30),
             scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$14.hasNext(Iterator.scala:390), 
             org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ClosingIterator$$anonfun$next$1.apply(ClosingIterator.scala:45), 
             org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ClosingIterator.failIfThrows(ClosingIterator.scala:86),
             org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ClosingIterator.next(ClosingIterator.scala:43),
             scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727), 
             org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ClosingIterator.foreach(ClosingIterator.scala:31),
             scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48), 
             scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ListBuffer.scala:178),
             scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ListBuffer.scala:45), 
             scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:259),
             org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ClosingIterator.to(ClosingIterator.scala:31),
             scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toList(TraversableOnce.scala:243), 
             org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ClosingIterator.toList(ClosingIterator.scala:31),
             org.neo4j.cypher.PipeExecutionResult.eagerResult(PipeExecutionResult.scala:100),
             org.neo4j.cypher.PipeExecutionResult.dumpToString(PipeExecutionResult.scala:103),
             org.neo4j.cypher.PipeExecutionResult.dumpToString$lzycompute(PipeExecutionResult.scala:143), 
             org.neo4j.cypher.PipeExecutionResult.dumpToString(PipeExecutionResult.scala:140),
             org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionResult.dumpToString(ExecutionResult.java:102),
             Neo4jQuery.query(Neo4jQuery.java:90), Neo4jQuery.main(Neo4jQuery.java:35),
             __SHELL3.run(__SHELL3.java:6), sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method), 
             sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57), 
             sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43), 
             java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606), bluej.runtime.ExecServer$3.run(ExecServer.java:725)]
```

I think I am passing the parameter "female" in the wrong way.

Comment: Your exception handling block is weird. Just use a logging framework (or java.util.logging) for logging error messages to disk.

Comment: You forgot to pass the parameter-map to cypher's execute method, `execute(query,params)`

Answer (score 2):

I should start with saying I am not familiar with the Java API for Neo4j. But from what I can see:

In Cypher

```
MATCH (n)
```

is incorrect. You need to describe a full path, like `MATCH (n)-->(m)` or `MATCH (n)-[:friend_of]-(m)`, or skip the match clause all together. In your particular example you don't need the match clause, so you can just skip it.

The second thing is - yes you're not passing the argument correctly - you can see some examples on how to pass arguments to the ExecutionEgine here: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-cypher-parameters-java.html

In your example you can do:

```
void query() {
    ExecutionResult result,;
    Transaction tx=null;
    ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine( graphDb );

    try
    {
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put("gender", "Female");
        tx=graphDb.beginTx();
        result = engine.execute("start n=node(*) where n.Gender ?= {gender} return n",params);
        System.out.println(result.dumpToString());
        tx.success();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        try
        {           
            File f=new File("trace.txt");
            BufferedWriter br=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f,true));
            tx.failure();
            k=Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace());
            System.out.println(k);
            br.write(k);
            br.close();
            throw new IOException();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
      }
    finally
    {
        tx.finish();
    }

}
```

Comment: P.S. if your query doesn't change at all you can also write it like this: `engine.execute("start n=node(*) where n.Gender ?= 'Female' return n");` and skip the Map completely.

Comment: You forgot to add the params map to the execute call. And usually you would only use Literals for really fixed values, i.e. constants.